# jQuery validate date group

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-validate

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I searched for a solution, but i couldn't find any.

I'm building a form and I'm using the jQuery-validation plugin to validate it.
In the form I have 3 input fields for the date of birth (DD/MM/YYYY).

I grouped the fields to get only one error message on the date. In the validation I specified minlength for all fields (2, 2 and 4 to get the DD/MM/YYYY).

While I'm entering a date the validation is working. But if the last entered field does validate, then the error message is gone! (I made some nice screenshots, but I'm not allowed to post images yet.)

I made a JSFiddle to clarify the problem:

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdeZ/pagjz6ft/64/)

Try entering a date of D/M/YYYY and then move te focus to "somefield" or D/MM/YYYY.

Any ideas on the solution? What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <style type='text/css'>
    input[type="text"]{
        border:0px;
    }

    .input_container{
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        margin:5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .btn_container{
        clear:both;
        margin:5px;    
    }

    div.error{
        border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    }

    label.error{
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #FF0000;
    }
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#frm').validate({
    rules:{
        DoB_day:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        DoB_month:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        DoB_year:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        }    
    },

    groups:{
        dateOfBirth: "DoB_day DoB_month DoB_year"
    },

    messages:{
        DoB_day:{
            required: "Please enter a date",
            minlength: "Format the day as DD"
        },
        DoB_month:{
            required: "Please enter a date",
            minlength: "Format the month as MM"
        },
        DoB_year:{
            required: "Please enter a date",
            minlength: "Format the year as YYYY"
        }                   
    },  

    highlight: function(element){
      $(element).parent('div').addClass('error');
    },

    unhighlight: function(element){
      $(element).parent('div').removeClass('error');
    },  

    errorLabelContainer: ".error",

});
});//]]>  

</script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="frm" name="frm" method="POST">

    <div class="input_container">
        <input type="text" id="DoB_day" name="DoB_day" size="1" placeholder="DD"/> /
        <input type="text" id="DoB_month" name="DoB_month" size="1" placeholder="MM" /> /
        <input type="text" id="DoB_year" name="DoB_year" size="3" placeholder="YYYY" />
    </div>

    <div class="input_container">
        <input type="text" id="somefield" placeholder="somefield" />
    </div>

    <div class="btn_container">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />    
    </div>

</form>

<label class="error"> &nbsp; </label>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using version 1.7 of the jQuery Validation plugin?  The latest version is 1.13.0 and a whole lot of bugs have been fixed since then.

Comment: I'm sorry, copied the wrong version. In the live version I was using version 1.12.0. I just updated them all to 1.13.0, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the validation to occur when the focus is lost from the DoB_year :

```
$("#DoB_year").blur(function () {
    $('#frm').valid();
});
```

Comment: That is not how you would "force validation".  The `.validate()` method is only how you would _initialize_ the plugin, not trigger validation.